# Order of css files in edge

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge, daterangepicker

> When declarations have the same importance (weight), origin and
>   specifity then the latter declaration wins

I'm working with daterangepicker library for my works and it is working well qua layout in all other browsers. Using the quoted paragraph, i define my css files later than the ones of library. However i am wondering why it is going weird in Edge:

[image]

*PS: also in this case my css file is loaded later than daterangepicker.css*

And here is the head:
[image]

Comment: Can you show the `head` where your css files are imported please?

Comment: I don't think that is what is happening... It seems more that there is no change occurring with background or border any way so it is ignoring it. Can you change just the background color in t.css to white and see what happens.

Comment: Please post your relevant code so a minimally working version can be tested.

Comment: @CayceK i changed the background color to the same manually. there was another color in ´daterangepicker.css´. So, it does not change the situation.

Comment: @ScottMarcus my project is so complex that i can't derive more code in order to test it. But what i know is that it is working properly in any other browsers.