# Edge does not respect css important and order

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I have two css files `daterangepicker.css` and `main.css`

For a certain element, i see the following in the console:

[image]

Although `main.css` is coming after `daterangepicker.css`, `main.css` is overriden. Its OK and i think its a known issue as asked [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36134422/order-of-css-files-in-edge).

But in this case, they are in the same specific level. Furthermore, in `main.css` i use `important` tags which are totally ignored:

```
.daterangepicker .ranges li.active, .daterangepicker .ranges li:hover {
  background: #D8AA0E !important;
  border: 1px solid #D8AA0E !important;
  font-weight: 500 !important;
}
```

what can be wrong with this?

Comment: why are you using 2 css files ? isn't it better to merge them and reuse the code you need? (I know it's not the answer to your question, but you wouldn't have this problem with single file)

Comment: its not good way. The other one is a external css file of a library which is continuously updated. Mixing their css with my css would make the development phase much harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearing cache is the solution...

Although the new css files are loaded and shown in the console, they are probably not applied to the screen. So, don't trust the css files you see after an update, just be sure that you clear your cache.